# Time Stamps are 2 hours behind

Tags: adobe, timestamp, flash-builder

I have a Adobe Flash Builder application that accesses a `MySQL` database through a `ColdFusion` server. In the `MySQL` database there is a table that is populated with time stamps.

When I bind the `ColdFusion` data service, that connects to the time stamp table, to the `DataGrid` in my application, anytime I add a new time stamp it saves it to the database correctly but it is 2 hours behind. I have checked the time and timezone settings on the database server, `ColdFusion` server, and the computer running Adobe Flash Builder and they are all correct for my time zone (Central -6). Does anyone know how I can get these time stamps to save with the correct time? I've tried everything that I could Google search pertaining to similar issues and so far I've come up with nothing. I'll provide any additional information that is needed to help diagnose the problem and find a solution.

Comment: Your timezone is probably not under suspicion unless it is either +02:00 or -02:00, but you could specify it more precisely nonetheless. "Central" what? A quick check in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` shows me about 20 different timezones that might possibly be known as "Central".

Comment: I updated my question. I meant Central Standard Time -06:00.

Comment: what is the output of "select now()" from your mysql server?  Also see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: @patrickmdnet `2012-12-27 14:30:35` The timestamp I created shortly after says `2012-12-27 12:31:55`. Weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the correct times, I had to implement the following code:

```
var timeStamp:Date = new Date();
var timezone:int = -4;
timeStamp.hours = timeStamp.hoursUTC + timezone;
```

Weird. All of the servers and clients have the correct time and they are all in the same time zone. Oh well, at least it works. Thanks for the help everyone!